# How do I return to where I was before i-search, goto line, etc

Tags: cursor, navigation

Let's say I'm on line Y, char X, and then do an i-search or do a goto line. Then I move around there a bit, but then I want to return to Y, X. How do I do this? Is there an automatic mechanism that remembers my position when doing common "jumps" to other places in the code?

I know Emacs has a function that changes point and mark, but `C-Space` causes highlighting as it's used for copy/paste so seems to be the wrong thing to use. Also, then I have to manually do something before I jump. I'm hoping for a way to magically return. This would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vim-like convenience jumps forth and back (`C-o` and `C-i` if I recall it correctly) built-in. Evil has it though.

As for built in mechanism, try `C-u` `C-Space` (pop-mark?) or `C-x` `C-Space` (pop-global-mark)

For example, if you in the middle of the buffer, move your cursor to the buffer end with `M->`. You can return to the place before jump with `C-u` `C-Space`.

Comment: `pop-mark` is exactly what I'm looking for! But exactly how does `pop-global-mark` work? A forward circuit of buffers where you have pressed `C-Space`? I tried doing `C-Space` on line 20 in my `.emacs`, but when `pop-global-mark` returned to `.emacs` it was on line 1. Generally, how/when do you use this function?

Comment: You have to remember that with `pop-global-mark` you will return to the saved mark. If for ex, you were on `.emacs` line 1 then searched for `use-package` -- you'll save the mark on line 1. And if you will `pop-global-mark` from another buffer you'll jump to exactly line 1 of your `.emacs`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to vanilla `C-u C-SPC` and `C-x C-SPC` (`pop-global-mark`), if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use those keys instead to more easily navigate among local and global marks, respectively.

**`C-SPC`** does this (by default) in `icicle-mode`:

> **`icicle-goto-marker-or-set-mark-command`** is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-@`, `C-SPC`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-marker-or-set-mark-command ARG)`
>
> Set mark or goto a marker.
>
> With no prefix arg or a prefix arg > 0, this is `set-mark-command`.
>   (This includes the cases of `C-u` and `C-u C-u`.)
>
> With a prefix arg = 0, this is `icicle-goto-any-marker`.
>
> With a prefix arg < 0, this is `icicle-goto-marker`.

---

> **`icicle-goto-marker`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search goto icicles icicle-goto-marker`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-marker)`
>
> Go to a marker in this buffer, choosing it by the line that includes it.
>   If `crosshairs.el` is loaded, then the target position is highlighted.
>
> By default, candidates are sorted in marker order, that is, with
>   respect to their buffer positions.  Use `C-M-,` or `C-,` to change the
>   sort order.
>
> During completion you can use these keys:
>
> `C-RET`   - Goto marker named by current completion candidate
>
> `C-down`  - Goto marker named by next completion candidate
>
> `C-up`    - Goto marker named by previous completion candidate
>
> `C-next`  - Goto marker named by next apropos-completion candidate
>
> `C-prior` - Goto marker named by previous apropos-completion candidate
>
> `C-end`   - Goto marker named by next prefix-completion candidate
>
> `C-home`  - Goto marker named by previous prefix-completion candidate
>
> `<S-delete>` - Delete marker named by current completion candidate
>
> When candidate action and cycling are combined (e.g. `C-next`), option
>   **`icicle-act-before-cycle-flag`** determines which occurs first.
>
> With prefix `C-M-` instead of `C-`, the same keys (`C-M-mouse-2`,
>   `<C-M-f1>`, `C-M-down`, and so on) provide help about candidates.
>
> Use `mouse-2`, `RET`, or `S-RET` to choose a candidate as the final
>   destination, or `C-g` to quit.  This is an Icicles command - see
>   command `icicle-mode`.

---

**`C-x C-SPC`** does this (by default) in `icicle-mode`:

> **`C-x C-SPC`** runs the command
>   `icicle-goto-global-marker-or-pop-global-mark` (found in
>   `icicle-mode-map`), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x C-@`, `C-x C-SPC`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-global-marker-or-pop-global-mark ARG)`
>
> With prefix arg < 0, `icicle-goto-global-marker`; else `pop-global-mark`.

---

> **`icicle-goto-global-marker`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search goto icicles icicle-goto-global-marker`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-global-marker)`
>
> Like `icicle-goto-marker`, but visits global, not local, markers.
>
> If user option **`icicle-show-multi-completion-flag`** is non-`nil`, then
>   each completion candidate is has two parts, the first of which is the
>   name of the marker’s buffer, and the second of which is the text from
>   the marker’s line.
>
> By default, candidates are sorted in buffer order and then marker
>   order, that is, buffer positions.  Use `C-M-,` or `C-,` to change the
>   sort order.  Remember too that you can use `C-A` to toggle
>   case-sensitivity (e.g., for buffer names).

---

> **`icicle-goto-any-marker`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search goto icicles icicle-goto-any-marker`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-any-marker)`
>
> Like `icicle-goto-marker`, but lets you visit markers in all buffers.
>   If user option **`icicle-show-multi-completion-flag`** is non-`nil`, then
>   each completion candidate is has two parts, the first of which is the
>   name of the marker’s buffer, and the second of which is the text from
>   the marker’s line.
>
> By default, candidates are sorted in buffer order and then marker
>   order, that is, buffer positions.  Use `C-M-,` or `C-,` to change the
>   sort order.  Remember too that you can use `C-A` to toggle
>   case-sensitivity (e.g., for buffer names).